# Not able to Authenticate using LDAP Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, ldap, directoryentry

```
 var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://adldap.test.com", UserName, Password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        try
        {
            var ds = new DirectorySearcher(de) { Filter = "samaccountname=" + UserName };
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            var sr = ds.FindOne(); //throws error: server not operational
            if (sr != null)
            {
                using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "TestDomian", UserName, Password))
                {
                    var validUser = ctx.ValidateCredentials(UserName, Password);
                    if ( validUser)                        {
                       {
                            model.IsLoggedIn = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return model;
        }
```

We have our own local authentication but one of our client wants to use their LDAP credentials for authentication. They have provide us with the LDAP url. They have also allowed our IP address through their firewall but I am still getting Server Not Operational Error. I am also not sure if the ValidationCredentials(UserName, Password) will work on an external LDAP server. Any info in right direction will help...thanks

Comment: Have you tried authenticating through Windows or some other tool to verify the other side is correctly configured?

Comment: @RonBeyer No Ron I haven't tried tht yet.. Let me see if I can do tht.

Comment: That would be the first thing I would do, so that I would verify that the other side works. Can't tell you how many times I've had a client say "ok, its ready" when its far from it.

Comment: @RonBeyer Ron I tried to use http://www.ldapbrowser.com/ tool for testing the connection. When I am trying to create a new profile, Entering the url in the Host and port 389. I am getting error "Error loading RootDSE for Host"

Comment: @RonBeyer Does tht mean some thing is wrong on the client config or I am using the wrong Port(Default Port) or something else ?

Comment: have you try check if the filter not case sensitive try change samaccountname to sAMAccountName

Comment: @Scorpio I'm not familiar with that tool but if you have an internal LDAP you can test against I would verify you have the right settings there, then verify you have the right connection settings with your third party.

Comment: @Scorpio, you're creating a new instance of `DirectoryEntry` using `Secure` authentication type. But I've read your comment (response to Ron) mentioning that you're using port `389` for your testing. Default`SSL` port is `636`. We you able to bind successfully?